# Missing 'name' key attribute on element action at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

Имеется следующий Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="asus.example.com.bitsandpizzas">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:label="@string/app_name" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

При сборке выдает ошибку:

> Error: Missing 'name' key attribute on element action at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:15:17-60 app main manifest (this file), line 14

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь внутри intent-filter объявить action со свойством label, но без свойства name. Скорее всего это очепятка.

Попробуйте так:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```